# How to mount a folder to guest OS

Tags: windows, linux, virtualbox, shared-folders

How can I mount any folder to guest OS (Ubuntu 11.04) the as host OS is Windows and I am using Sun VirtualBox?

I have done like this. In VirtualBox' settings » Shared folders » Add » Added new folder

Now in the terminal of the guest OS I typed:

```
mount -t sharedfoldername mount-point
```

But it is not working.

Comment: I know it's against our rules, and I posted an answer, but improving your Google-fu is a must if you want to use Ubuntu for example. :)

Comment: "It is not working" is not a good problem description. Have you literally typed `sharedfoldername` and `mount-point` or what was the actual command you used? How do your VirtualBox settings look like exactly? Does the command show an error, or does nothing happen at all? There is a lot missing in your question that would make it possible for others to give a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo mount -t vboxsf SHARENAME /media/vboxshared`

So in your case:
`sudo mount -t vboxsf sharedfoldername mount-point`

(With `-t vboxsf`, you specify that the mounted filesystem is Virtualbox's shared filesystem. Aaand that's it.)